# Selection sort for doubles in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have written the selection sort method before for ints, but right now I am working with an array of doubles. I have tried changing the variables to doubles, but I am still getting a "Cannot convert from double to int". Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
//Original selection sort for ints
public static void selectionSort (int... arr)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, smallest = 0;
    int temp = 0;

    for (i = 0;i<arr.length - 1;i++)
    {
        smallest = i;
        for (j = 1; j<arr.length - 1; j++)
        {
            if (arr[j]<arr[smallest])
                smallest = j;
        }
        temp = arr[smallest];
        arr[smallest] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = temp;

    }
}

//Attempted selection sort with doubles
public static void selectionSort (double...arr )
{
    double i = 0.0, j = 0.0, smallest = 0.0;
    double temp = 0.0;

    for (i = 0.0;i<arr.length - 1.0;i++)
    {
        smallest = i;
        for (j = 1.0; j<arr.length - 1.0; j++)
        {
            if (arr[j]<arr[smallest]) //error here with smallest and j
                smallest = j;
        }
        temp = arr[smallest]; //error here with smallest
        arr[smallest] = arr[i]; //error here with smallest and i
        arr[i] = temp; //error here with i

    }
}
```

Comment: Array index can't be double, convert `smallest`, `i` and `j`  double to int.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you've also used double for indexing the arrays. So try this instead:

```
public static void selectionSort (double...arr)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, smallest = 0;
    double temp = 0.0;

    for (i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++)
    {
        smallest = i;
        for (j = 1; j < arr.length - 1; j++)
        {
            if (arr[j] < arr[smallest])
                smallest = j;
        }
        temp = arr[smallest];
        arr[smallest] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = temp;
    }
}
```

As you can see you still have doubles as parameter, and the `temp`-value and `arr`-array are also still doubles, but the indexes that are used for the array are ints.

Indexes are always int. For example, when we have an array of Strings, we still use ints for the indexes:

```
String[] sArray = {
    "word1",
    "word2",
    "word3"
}
int index = 1;
String result = sArray[index]; // As you can see we use an int as index, and the result is a String
// In your case, the index is still an int, but the result is a double
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for the in depth explanation! I'll give you the green check in a minute when it allows me to

Comment: +1, but I think you would also explain that for loop need everything inside the statement have the same type.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you change the for loop to doubles?

```
for (i = 0.0;i<arr.length - 1.0;i++)
```

It does only work with `int`'s for the indexes of the arrays.

Comment: I thought to make it compatible with doubles everything had to be doubles

Comment: @homidhomi4 No, just keep the for loop from your previous snippet.

Comment: No, for loop also works good if everything inside the for statement is double.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use subscript value as int check out with that. Use like this

```
int i = 0,j =0,smallest = 0;
```

access array values using these